# Unable to install GoogleCloudSDKInstaller on windows 2008 R2 standard

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, google-cloud-platform, cloud, sdk

I am getting an error which says the following when trying to install `GoogleCloudSDKInstaller` on windows 2008 R2 standard server.

```
Download failed: HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden

Output folder: C\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK
Downloading Google Cloud SDK core.
Download failed: HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden.
```

The firewall is disabled on the server. Please help me fix the problem. I am able to install other software like python 3.7.0. I am unable to attach the screenshot as I don't have sufficient points.

Comment: I am also requesting support from here https://www.cloudconnectcommunity.com/ccc/ls/community/google-cloud-platform/post/6132205233635328

Answer (score 1):

Please install following these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows). You are getting a 403 HTTP status, but the official download link is open though, it doesn't require you to authenticate.

You may either be using a different download link or have custom settings on your network that are affecting how you reach the download link, so the other thing to test would be downloading while being connected to a different network.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installer as Admin?  That is not a GoogleCloudSDK issue, but a Windows permission issue.  Also, you could try installing in elsewhere...

Comment: Probably should have suggested this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: As I have said before I was able to install other softwares[python] but not this one. I am logged in as an administrator and trying to install the same.

Comment: We are able to do the same installation on our local machine which is Windows 10 and is 64 bit and it works as checked here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Servers, Internet Explorer is set for Enhanced Security Configuration. This setting prevents you from running the installer above. Disable Enhanced Security Configuration first, restart Internet Explorer and then run the installer. For instructions on disabling Enhanced Security on your Windows Server Instance, open Windows Help and Support and search for “IE ESC”.

Comment: Jason, I tried this, but it did not work for me. On the server IE version installed is 8 and I have also tried bringing down the privacy to low or Accept All Cookies and also the same in the Security tab. We also tried installing it in a different folder on the server, but it did not work. Should I sign out from and sign back in on the server for the change to get effective?